# Power Query merge distinct lists into table

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a excel table with data in multiple columns.
I am trying to create another table that will be used for in-cell dropdown with only unique values.
I need to get unique values independently between each columns.

Source table

```
geo   product   type
g1    p1        t1
g1    p2        t1
g1    p3        t2
g1    p4        t1
g2    p1        t2
g2    p2        t1
g2    p3        t2
g2    p4        t1
```

Expected result:

```
geo   product   type
g1    p1        t1
g2    p2        t2
null  p3        null
null  p4        null
```

I can get unique columns as lists

```
geo_list = List.Distinct(Table.Column(Source, "geo"))
product_list = List.Distinct(Table.Column(Source, "product"))
type_list = List.Distinct(Table.Column(Source, "type"))
```

But cannot find a way how to merge it into one table without any kind of join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64802547/move-up-values-when-null-power-query), you can use [Table.FromColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-fromcolumns) to assemble a table from your lists.

```
Table.FromColumns(
    {
        List.Distinct(Source[geo]),
        List.Distinct(Source[product]),
        List.Distinct(Source[type])
    },
    {"geo","product","type"}
)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is wonderful. I was already in the middle of creating my custom gigantic function.

Comment: Do you have also some quick win to apply it on table regardless number and names of columns?

Comment: It's would be the same as in the edit part of the post I linked, except `List.Distinct` instead of `List.RemoveNulls` and `Source` instead of `Pivot`.

Answer (score 0):

With Office 365 you don't even need Power Query for that, it's much easier with `UNIQUE`:

`=UNIQUE(Table1[geo])`

[image]

> But cannot find a way how to merge it into one table without any kind of join.

I think you should not try to put them into one table, but keep as separate. The idea behind tables is that each row contains information related to each other which is apparently not the case for your data.

Comment: That is true and I am aware of this however if you want to use it in data validation list you get error (if you use directly Unique fx directly there) or you need to create pretty complicated formula to catch dynamically resized range. If I had it in excel table, all I have to do is put there named range and ignore blank values.