# How to shift empty cells up in Power Query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-embedded

I am currently having such kind of table:

[image]

This is the code that is used for this table:

```
let
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/exchangeInfo")),
symbols = Source[symbols],
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(symbols, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), ExtraValues.Error),
#"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"symbol", "filters"}, {"Symbol", "Column1.filters"}),
#"Expanded Column1.filters" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "Column1.filters"),
#"Expanded Column1.filters1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1.filters", "Column1.filters", {"tickSize", "stepSize"}, {"tickSize", "stepSize"})
in
#"Expanded Column1.filters1"
```

And this is the result I would like to get:

[image]

How do I do that?
Basically I would like to remove empty cells, shift filled cells up and then remove duplicates, so the final result would be exactly like in the image 2.

Comment: Related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64802547) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65251258)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi this below solution is assuming that Symbol column contains unique values for each value for both tickSize and stepSize columns.

1. Create two copies of these tables
2. In the first one remove all the null values in tickSize column
   and remove duplicates in Symbol column
3. In the second one remove all the nulls in stepSize column and remove
   duplicates in Symbol column.
4. And after words merge those two tables using Symbol column (inner
   join) and expand the second table and get the stepSize into that
   table.